# Can't read an XML in Stream

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, stream

I have a little problem with an XML file and a `Stream`. I create and save an XML file in a `Stream`, encrypt the `Stream` and then save it to a normal file.

I want to read this XML, however I can only do this if I use a `FileStream` and write a decrypted file to disk.

Is there a way to decrypt and keep this file in memory?

This is my code:

```
XMLDecriptato = New MemoryStream()
Using stream_readerX As New StreamReader(XMLDecriptato, Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    XMLDecriptato.SetLength(0)
    Dim FStreamCrypted As FileStream = File.Open(varTitolo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    FStreamCrypted.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    CryptStream(Pass, FStreamCrypted, XMLDecriptato, Type.Decrypt)

    'try to read the stream
    Dim xDocumentX As New XmlDocument()
    xDocumentX.Load(stream_readerX) 'here is the error
End Using
```

It keeps saying that the `Stream` is closed. I have tried also another way. The only one that works is to write the stream to the hard disk with a `FileStream`.

And that is the Encrypt/Decrypt Sub:

```
Public Sub CryptStream(ByVal Psw As String, ByVal IN_Stream As Stream, ByVal OUT_Stream As Stream, ByVal CrtType As CryptType)
    Dim AES_Provider As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()

    Dim Key_Size_Bits As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 1024 To 1 Step -1
        If (aes_provider.ValidKeySize(i)) Then
            Key_Size_Bits = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Dim Block_Size_Bits As Integer = AES_Provider.BlockSize
    Dim Key() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim IV() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim Salt() As Byte = "//my salt//"
    MakeKeyAndIV(Psw, Salt, Key_Size_Bits, Block_Size_Bits, Key, IV)

    Dim Crypto_Transform As ICryptoTransform = Nothing

    Select Case CrtType
        Case CryptType.Encrypt
            Crypto_Transform = AES_Provider.CreateEncryptor(key, iv)
        Case CryptType.Decrypt
            Crypto_Transform = AES_Provider.CreateDecryptor(key, iv)
    End Select
    If Crypto_Transform Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Try
        Using Crypto_Stream As New CryptoStream(OUT_Stream, Crypto_Transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Const Block_Size As Integer = 1024
            Dim Buffer(Block_Size) As Byte
            Dim Bytes_Read As Integer
            Do
                Bytes_Read = IN_Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Block_Size)
                If (Bytes_Read = 0) Then Exit Do

                Crypto_Stream.Write(Buffer, 0, Bytes_Read)
            Loop
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Crypto_Transform.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if removing it changes anything, but this line seems pretty useless to me: `XMLDecriptato.SetLength(0)`. You've not done anything with the `MemoryStream` yet, so setting its length shouldn't do much...

Comment: Also please show us the declaration for `ClsCrypt`.

Comment: Memory stream, anyone?

Comment: _'here is the error_. What is the error you are getting? Also as stated you aren't using the `MemoryStream` and also as asked, include the declaration of `ClsCrypt`. With this information we _may_ be able to provide some assistance. Please include this information in your question by clicking _edit_.

Comment: @Jinx88909 : He's using the `MemoryStream` both in the constructor of the `StreamReader` and in the `ClsCrypt.Stream` method: `ClsCrypt.Stream(Pass, FStreamCrypted, ***XMLDecriptato***, Type.Decrypt)`

Comment: @VisualVincent my bad. I'm on my phone now and had missed that bit, just seen the 'setlength'.

Comment: @Jinx88909 : I understand. I'm on my phone right now too, though so am I most of the time. :)

Comment: Im new here so i dont know if my reply will alert you all. Anyway...
@VisualVincent I know that this line "XMLDecriptato.SetLength(0)" is useless, but also if i remove it, wont work. ClsCryp is a common encrypt class with rijndael. Input is a "Stream" and output is another "Stream" (then not a Filestream and/or memorystream).

Comment: @Jinx88909 With the current code i get something like "The stream is closed" but with other test i get something like "Stream is not readable". For the Crypt class i will include id when i go back to home, but as i said, the input is a Stream and the output also.

Comment: You notified us alright :). The reason why we need the `ClsCrypt` class declaration is for us to be able to test the code.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes yes i know why, i will edit my post when i go back to home. Also if i find that is useless because the function work if i try to write the returned stream in a file, i cant just open it in momery. :)

Comment: Well we're here to help you open it in the memory!

Comment: @VisualVincent Here we go.. but as i said the problem is not the sub, because i can write in a file a returned stream with a `FileStream` but i cant read it direct in memory

Comment: The problem could be anywhere, I still needed the sub to test the code ;). Speaking of which, I need the `MakeKeyAndIV` method too.

Comment: Oh wait, found the tutorial you were using... Don't bother then. :)

Comment: Okay, I have found a solution to your problem. If it worked, please mark my answer as accepted by pressing the check mark on the left of my post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when `CryptoStream.Dispose()` is called by the [**`Using/End Using` block**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx), the `CryptoStream` also disposes the underlying stream (in this case your `MemoryStream`).
 This behaviour can be confirmed by checking [**Microsoft's Reference Source**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,3bb570e73c03705d).

Since the `CryptoStream` doesn't have a `LeaveOpen` flag like the `StreamReader` does since [**.NET 4.5 and up**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx), I removed the `Using` block and wrote the necessary calls on my own for your method.

The changes:

```
Public Sub CryptStream(ByVal Psw As String, ByVal IN_Stream As Stream, ByVal OUT_Stream As Stream, ByVal CrtType As CryptType, Optional ByVal LeaveOpen As Boolean = False)
    ...code...

    Try
        Dim Crypto_Stream As New CryptoStream(OUT_Stream, Crypto_Transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        Const Block_Size As Integer = 1024
        Dim Buffer(Block_Size) As Byte
        Dim Bytes_Read As Integer
        Do
            Bytes_Read = IN_Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Block_Size)
            If (Bytes_Read = 0) Then Exit Do

            Crypto_Stream.Write(Buffer, 0, Bytes_Read)
        Loop

        If Crypto_Stream.HasFlushedFinalBlock = False Then Crypto_Stream.FlushFinalBlock()

        If LeaveOpen = False Then
            Crypto_Stream.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    ...code...
End Sub
```

And since data will be fed into the `MemoryStream` its position will have changed, so you have to reset that too before loading the XML document:

```
XMLDecriptato = New MemoryStream()
Using stream_readerX As New StreamReader(XMLDecriptato, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    Dim FStreamCrypted As FileStream = File.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    CryptStream(Pass, FStreamCrypted, XMLDecriptato, CryptType.Decrypt, True) 'True = Leave the underlying stream open.

    XMLDecriptato.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) 'Reset the MemoryStream's position.

    Dim xDocumentX As New XmlDocument()
    xDocumentX.Load(stream_readerX)
End Using
```

As you might have noticed I removed the `FStreamCrypted.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` line. This was because you've just opened the stream and done nothing with it, so the position will already be at 0.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't believe.. before a "Using" i had a dim like that but still my stream was closed or "not readabled". I just dont understand where was my error :( maybe `HasFlushedFinalBlock`? because i have tried to remove the line `If LeaveOpen = False Then Crypto_Stream.Dispose()` and force it to Dispose but works anyway now.

Comment: @Tyler : `i have tried to remove the line and force it to Dispose but works anyway now.` - That can't be right, because when `Dispose()` is called _**it will**_ close the underlying memory stream.

Comment: @Tyler : `before a "Using" i had a dim like that but still my stream was closed or "not readabled".` - That was likely because you didn't call `FlushFinalBlock()`. The method will ensure that all data is written to the underlying stream and that nothing is left in the buffer.

Comment: So that is.. when i used a `Dim` i dont had `FlushFinalBlock()` but the stream was "open" and i get an error "stream is not readable" but with `Using` the stream was closed. For this reason a get errors in both code! Thank you Mr. Vincent, nice help ;)

Comment: @Tyler : No problem, glad I could help!